# Is there a way to install a toolbox from Matlab's command windows?

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab on a high performance computer (HPC). But they don't have a toolbox I need. I need to install it . Is it possible that I install a toolbox via matlab script locally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at Matlab's [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html), `genpath` and `savepath` functions.

Either use `addpath(genpath(...))` in the command line followed by `savepath` to permanently (and globally) add it to the path. Or else you could have `addpath(genpath(...))` at the start of your main script to just make sure you always have that toolbox loaded for relevant sessions without permanently adding a toolbox that other users might nit need to the path.

Oh wait, are you asking if you can install a toolbox you don't have at all like from a package repository? In that case I don't think so.