# Installing add-ons without display

Tags: matlab

There are more and more packages on Matlab Central that are shared in the form of *add-ons* or *custom toolboxes* (extension `.mltbx`).

I'm using such toolboxes and when on my desktop I can simply install them by clicking on them. However my code is eventually deployed on a cluster, where none of the nodes has these toolboxes installed and none of the Matlab instance is run with display.

How can I install add-ons programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to install a toolbox from Matlab's command windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500923/is-there-a-way-to-install-a-toolbox-from-matlabs-command-windows)

Comment: You can probably just download/install the toolbox on one computer, and copy the relevant `*.m` files. I couldn't test that though.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate. The linked post assumes direct access to the folder to add to MATLAB's path, which we don't have here.

Comment: @hbaderts What excaza said. I don't think this is a duplicate because it's not immediately obvious how to access the toolbox contents.

Comment: Imho, the *question* is more or less exactly the same. I agree that the answer is really different and that this answer is really helpful - but it would also be helpful to the linked question. This is why I voted to mark both questions as duplicate, that way everybody looking at the linked question would profit of this answer here. But if you disagree that's fine - that's what the close-voting system is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poking around MATLAB's subroutines I couldn't figure out an obvious way to handle this programmatically without at least some user input.

That being said, the `*.mltbx` package is really just a `*.zip` file, which we can access directly inside MATLAB. To illustrate this, I've created a quick toolbox using my code prototyping folder, `testcode-matlab.mltbx`.

If you extract the contents of this file using [`unzip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unzip.html): `unzip('testcode-matlab.mltbx', 'temp');` you should be left with something like the following:

[image: root folder]

If we examine the contents of `fsroot`, we see that it's the folder of data packaged into the toolbox:

[image: folder contents]

So we can take this folder, move it to where we want using something like [`copyfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html), and then add it to the MATLAB path using [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html):

```
copyfile('.\temp\fsroot', '.\mytoolboxes\testtoolbox');
addpath('.\mytoolboxes\testtoolbox');
```

Answer (score 4):

As of R2016a, there is a [MATLAB API to install them:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.addons.toolbox.installtoolbox.html)

```
matlab.addons.toolbox.installToolbox('mytoolbox.mltbx')
```